# Tool For Load Testing Various SQL Alternatives in Big Data

Tags: jmeter, bigdata, load-testing, mapr, apache-drill

We are working on Deciding which SQL alternative Among Impala,Drill,Spark-SQL fits our use case. As a Part of this we need to do a Load Test on them, Do we have any Load Testing Tools? I know there is J Meter from Apache.

Also Do we have Any Tool similar to Cloudera Manager in MApR Distribution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of 3 free and open source tools capable of load testing databases using JDBC protocol, they are:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- and you already know about [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide for aforementioned tools overview, sample load reports and feature comparison matrix, hopefully it'll help you to choose the right option.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm Gatling's project leader.

It doesn't make sense to look for a generic load test tool for this.

Such tool would let you test how your JDBC driver, your database and your database model perform. Typically, you want to compare different solutions, like how MySQL compete with PostGresql against a similar model.

But here, you want to benchmark high level frameworks, with the same JDBC driver, database and database model.

You'd have to write your own benchmarks.